# checkbox onclick() bug in listview

Tags: java, android, checkbox, onclick

I've got a strange bug when I am clicking on checkbox (or selecting the item) trough a ListView.

Due to my custom base adapter I want to execute setItemChecked() everytime a checkbox is checked or not.

The first click do nothing (looks like it is not clicked), but I checked it whether onclick() was fired or not and it did. So it just looked not clicked.

The second click works apparently and the third as well.

But then it restarts and the next click does not change the look of the checkbox.

Furthermore if I click on other checkboxes in one of the "click-stages" the checkboxes will not behave like they should do..

Here is the important excerpt of my BaseAdapter Class with the functions:

```
final int finalPosition = position;

checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (((CheckBox) arg0).isChecked()) {
            ((ListView)parent).setItemChecked(finalPosition, true);
        } else {
            ((ListView)parent).setItemChecked(finalPosition, false);
        }
    }
});

convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        checkbox.toggle();
        if (checkbox.isChecked()) {
            ((ListView)parent).setItemChecked(finalPosition, true);
        } else {
            ((ListView)parent).setItemChecked(finalPosition, false);
        }
    }
});
```

And this is the whole class:

```
public class ShoppingListBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private ArrayList<ShoppingListEntry> m_itemList;
private Context m_context;
private LayoutInflater m_inflater;

public ShoppingListBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ShoppingListEntry> shoppingListEntryArrayList) {
    m_itemList = shoppingListEntryArrayList;
    m_context = context;
    m_inflater = (LayoutInflater.from(context));
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return m_itemList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView = m_inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
    TextView info = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_info);
    final CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);

    String itemTitle;
    String productBrand = m_itemList.get(position).getProductBrand().toString();
    if ( !productBrand.isEmpty() ) {
        itemTitle = productBrand + " " + m_itemList.get(position).getProductName().toString();
    } else {
        itemTitle = m_itemList.get(position).getProductName().toString();
    }
    title.setText(itemTitle);

    String itemInfo;
    String productAmount = m_itemList.get(position).getProductAmount();
    float productPrice = m_itemList.get(position).getProductPrice();
    itemInfo = productAmount + ", " + productPrice + "€";
    info.setText(itemInfo);

    final int finalPosition = position;

    checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (((CheckBox) arg0).isChecked()) {
                ((ListView)parent).setItemChecked(finalPosition, true);
            } else {
                ((ListView)parent).setItemChecked(finalPosition, false);
            }
        }
    });

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            checkbox.toggle();
            if (checkbox.isChecked()) {
                ((ListView)parent).setItemChecked(finalPosition, true);
            } else {
                ((ListView)parent).setItemChecked(finalPosition, false);
            }

        }
    });


    return convertView;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `setOnCheckChange`  Instead, like this:

```
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

//if true, your checkbox will be selected, else unselected
            checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener.setChecked(item.isSelected());

checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            });
```

in this way when you want to set its state(is checked or not) your listener will not call and after that will be called by changing its state,
Just test it and let me know the result

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!

I also tried this possibility but unfortunately there is the same behavior.

Besides that I dont have the function `checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);` and `checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener.setChecked(item.isSelected());`

I only have `checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener()`

Comment: I have no idea but now it is working perfectly..

I just changed the `getItem(int position) {return m_itemList.get(position);}` and `getItemID(int position) {return position;}` functions

Comment: Thanks for your help!